# LESS generates wrong code for grid-template declaration with forward slashes

Tags: css, less, css-grid

I am using this CSS for my CSS grid declaration:

```css
#slider_area {
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr / 1fr 32%;
  grid-column-gap: 8px;
  grid-row-gap: 4px;
}
```

but it converts to:

```css
#slider_area {
    grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr 32%;
    grid-column-gap: 8px;
    grid-row-gap: 4px;
}
```

in my LESS, and the page view breaks.

You can check it here:

https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/less-to-css.html

Where can I report it, if it is a bug? And is there a workaround?

Comment: Looks like it was [just reported](https://www.drupal.org/project/less/issues/3118667), probably due to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that LESS thinks this is a mathematical operation.

For example if you write:

```css
#slider_area #A { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2; }
```

Then it will output:

```css
#slider_area #A { grid-area: 0.25; }
```

You can make use of [escaping](http://lesscss.org/#escaping) to workaround the problem:

> Escaping allows you to use any arbitrary string as property or
>   variable value. Anything inside ~"anything" or ~'anything' is used as
>   is with no changes except interpolation.

```css
#slider_area {
  grid-template: ~"1fr 1fr 1fr / 1fr 32%";
  grid-column-gap: 8px;
  grid-row-gap: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Feels like a bug in LESS, you can use this workaround:

```css
#slider_area {
  @grid-template: "1fr 1fr 1fr / 1fr 32%";
  grid-template: e(@grid-template);
  grid-column-gap: 8px;
  grid-row-gap: 4px;
}
```

the `e` function will just strip the parentheses from a variable

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60600186/3597276), this is a bug with LESS, where the forward slash is interpreted as a division slash ([see the report](https://www.drupal.org/project/less/issues/3118667)).

So instead of using the `grid-template` shorthand property:

```
grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr / 1fr 32%;
```

Just stick to the longhand properties:

```
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 32%;
```